# array - efficiency & general approach towards the question

Tags: eclipse

Edit
**After quite a bit of playing around with my code I have written few versions, one of them is what I sought for.

Comment: You said some numbers are missing and replaced with zero, yet in the example it seems that they were replaced by -1. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

1. Create a helper `Set` with all the numbers from 1 to 100 - O(n) in time and space
2. Create an (initially) empty `Set` to record the indexes with 0s - O(1)
3. Go over the array - O(n):

   1. If the value is 0, add the index to the index set
   2. If the value isn't 0, remove it from the helper Set
4. Go over the helper set, and assign the remaining values to the indexes saved to the index set - O(m), where m<=n

All in all - an O(n) solution in time and space.

In java:

```java
int[] numbers = /* the array with missing numbers */
Set<Integer> allNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).boxed().Collect(Collectors.toSet()); 
Set<Ineteger> missingIndexes = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    if (numbers[i] == 0) {
        missingIndexes.add(i);
    } else {
        allNumbers.remove(i);
    }
}

Iterator<Integer> numberIter = allNumbers.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> indexIter = missingIndexes.iterator();

while (numberIter.hasNext() && indexIter.hasNext()) {
    numbers[indexIter.next()] = numberIter.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can sacrifice a little more space to optimize for time.

Basically just create another `missing` array and fill it with what's missing by traversing your `helper` array.

Modified your original solution.

```
  int input  [] = {5,6,0,3,0,2,1};
  int output [] = new int[input.length];  
  boolean [] helper  = new boolean[input.length];

  for(int i = 0; i <input.length; i++)
  {
      if(input[i] != 0)
          helper[i] = true;
  }

  int missing [] = new int[input.length];
  int missingCount = 0;

   for(int j = 0; j < helper.length; j++)
  {
      if(!helper[j]){ 
         missing[missingCount++] = j;

      }
  }
  missingCount = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < input.length; j++){
      if(input[j]==0){
           input[j]=missing[missingCount++];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, why do you think it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Below code can find the missing element and add them back in O(n) complexity:

> ***notFound*** - Will store index or location of input array having number
>   with zero
>
> ***numberDetails*** - Contains details of numbers whether its present in
>   input array or not(true or false)
>
> Example: input[3] = false means 4 (3+1) is not present in input array
>         , input[4] = true  means 5 (4+1) is  present in input array

```
        int input[] = { 5, 6, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1 };
        int notFound[] = new int[input.length];
        boolean[] numberDetails = new boolean[input.length];
        int notFoundIndex=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            if(input[i]==0) {
                notFound[notFoundIndex++]=i;
            }
            else {
                numberDetails[input[i]-1]=true;
            }

        }
        notFoundIndex=0;
        for(int j=0;j<numberDetails.length;j++) {
            if(!numberDetails[j]) {
                input[notFound[notFoundIndex++]] = j+1;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```